# Applying restriction to user

Tags: php, database, csv, upload

im working on a PHP-based login system where a user can upload a CSV file to the database. however the user is restricted to can only upload a file 5 times per session and then he cant upload any more.can anyone give me some idea the best way to accomplish this? tq.

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['uploadcount']++ > 5) { die("limit exceeded"});` it's not exactly rocket science...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that come to mind.  One would be to have the session keep track of how many uploads the person has made with a simple counter.  When you're processing the file they uploaded, you would first check to make sure they hadn't already uploaded five, and then simply increase the count.  Once they reach 5, you would also stop displaying the upload form.

Another option, which may be unnecessarily complicated for this purpose (but would still be a good practice) would be to keep a database record of every file a user uploads, with details.  This way, you would know when they last uploaded a file, how many they had in a certain stretch of time, etc.